# Code is breaking after I clicked Ctrl+S in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

If I'm clicking CTRL + S in VSCode, the code is breaking. Please see the screenshots

**Before**

[image]

**After I clicked CTRL+S**

[image]

Comment: Before diving into any code, try to uninstall all your extensions and reinstall them to see it works or not. If not, try to uninstall VS Code and install it again. It sounds a lot, but it's better than digging into some code.

Comment: I think it was being done by 2 extensions `JS-CSS-HTML formatter` or `beautify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have install the extension .Please check at the bottom of you Vs code . It should be JavaScript React. If it is not , select JavaScript React from the list
[image]

Comment: which extension